# how to navigate multiple location using single cd command in linux

Tags: shell, scripting

I am writing a shell script to copy the logs from multiple location to one destination location. 
I want use `cp` command only once to navigate to all logs location.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: What do you imagine that meaning? Could you [edit] in an example/some examples?

Answer (score 3):

To copy files from multiple locations and collect them in one place, you do not need to `cd` to those locations.

```
cp /the/1st/path/file1.txt /the/2nd/path/file2.txt /the/3rd/path/file3.txt ./
```

This will copy the files `file1.txt`, `file2.txt` and `file3.txt` from their various locations to the current directory.  If there are any file in the current directory that already have one of those names, they will be overwritten.

If all files have the same name, then you would have to do one `cp` fore each of them, renaming them in the process:

```
cp /the/1st/path/file.txt ./file1.txt
cp /the/2nd/path/file.txt ./file2.txt
cp /the/3rd/path/file.txt ./file3.txt
```